# Android studio stuck on “Gradle：dependencies ‘switchView2:_debugUnitTestCompile’”

Tags: android, android-studio, import

I set the project 'switchView2' as a library for Time_Elf.
Now I want to import Time_Elf to Android Studio.

I chose "import project (Eclipse ADT,Gradle,etc.)",

then I meet the problem,how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

OK!~~I find just to wait patiently.It is a mistake.